# Open a port on mac for locally running spark

Tags: linux, macos, apache-spark, port, spark-submit

I am running a stand-alone Spark 3.2.1 locally, on my mac, installed via brew. This is for low-cost (free) unit testing purposes. I am starting this instance via pyspark command from terminal and able to access the instance web ui.

I am also trying to run spark-submit locally (from the same mac) to run a pyspark script on the pyspark instance described above. When specifying the --master :7077 I am getting the "connection refused" error. It does not look like the port 7077 is open on my mac.

How do I open the port 7077 on my mac such that I can access it from my mac via spark-submit, but other machines on the same network cannot?

Could someone share clear steps with explanations?

Much appreciated :)
Michael

Answer (score 0):

Check your spark master process is running.

It must be like following output.

```
jps

$PID Master
$PID Worker
```

If spark process is not running,
run script `$SPARK_HOME/sbin/start-master.sh` in your shell first.
also `$SPARK_HOME/sbin/start-worker.sh`.

and then check if process listen on 7077 port with following command.

`sudo lsof -nP -i:7077 | grep LISTEN`